# Pandas Pivot_Table with link in each column and row (to_html)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I would like create links for each column/row of a pandas pivot_table that I return from Flask with to_html funcion.

For example:

[In each column/row I need a link with the month and branch to return the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeTYZ.png)

My code:

```
 dfResult = pd.pivot_table(df1, 
                        #columns=['Branch'],
                        values=['Vessels Count'],
                        columns=['Branch'],
                        index=['Month'], 
                        aggfunc=np.sum,
                        margins=True,
                        margins_name='Total',                        
                        fill_value=0).astype(np.float64).round(2).T

    return(dfResult.to_html(classes='mystyle'))
```

Thanks in advance!